# unable to snapshots and storing while using rhino python script

Tags: python, rhino3d

```py
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

import random as rn


render_folder="C:\\Users\\Abdul Azeem\\Desktop\\design computing\\render\\"

num_of_frames = rs.GetInteger('Number of Frames to output',10)


def render_step(render_folder,sequence_num):
    
    
    file_name = str(int(sequence_num)).zfill(5)
        
    file_path = " " + render_folder + file_name + ".png"
        
    rs.Command("_-ViewCaptureToFile" + file_path + "_Enter" )

for frame in range(num_of_frames):
    
    
    circle=rs.AddCircle((0,0,0),10)
    
    x=frame*2
    y=frame*5
    z=frame*10
    
    rs.MoveObject(circle,(x,y,z))
   
    render_step(render_folder,frame)
    rs.DeleteObject(circle)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please describe the issue you are having, add tracebacks and ask a question about what you don't understand and we will try to help.

Comment: please read title

Comment: please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the command line you'll see "Save file name ( Unit=pixels  Width=1387  Height=614  Scale=1  LockAspectRatio=No  DrawGrid=No  DrawWorldAxes=No  DrawCPlaneAxes=No  TransparentBackground=No  NumberOfPasses=500  Autoname=ViewCapture  Browse ): **E:\export_trials\00009.png_Enter**"

the "_Enter" got joined to the command string.

use " _Enter" starting with a space instead of "_Enter"